# France: New visa application when you are already in the country with another visa

Tags: working-visas, france, resident-permit, indian-citizens, residence-cards

I am an Indian citizen and having stayed in France for a long time (~7 years), holding a residence permit [Carte de Séjour - Salarié en Mission], which I obtained through the company that brought me to France on assignment. I have had the residence permit renewed multiple times since then, with the last renewal extending the validity until end of 2019. I would like to have some information on 2 points:

1. Is it possible to apply for a completely new visa while still in France, for a job contract with another French company? After some research on the net, I understand some of the key points to consider is that the new job offer is provided by a different company from the one that brought me to France, and that I hold a residence permit with Salarié en Mission, which is restricted to the company and work that I am currently assigned to.
2. Similar to question asked in the link [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9378/france-what-happens-to-your-immigration-status-when-you-leave-the-job-that-brou) (which was very helpful and clear btw, thank you @Gala), is there a timeframe to leave the country if I quit the company that brought me to France?

I did visit the Préfecture a few times to inquire about these questions, but was not able to get a concise answer, and unfortunately the reply seems to vary with each visit. Also, it seemed to me that the personnel always is confused in the case of Salarié en Mission residence permits. I was informed that a change of status is not possible and that I would have to return to my country to have any kind of change (new visa, etc).

There seems to be new rules, regulations and types of French visa and newer policies starting even this year, which make this more confusing for me.

Any information would be very helpful.